# Class access methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, object

How can I access a class which is in another project in C#. Please keep in mind that I cannot add any reference due to creating circular referencing.

Is there any way?

Comment: "*I cannot add any reference due to creating circular referencing*" - In short, You don't. You either move the common code to a common project. or return an event, or use an interface to share a contract

Comment: "Please keep in mind that I cannot add any reference due to creating circular referencing" in this case it is impossible. This should be avoided and it can easily avoided, but to be able to help more I'd need your project structure

Comment: Reflection is your friend if your code organisation has screwed so badly.

Comment: No to reflection, and that's coming from someone who has "reflection" in his name. Straighten out your references. Refactor your code to have a clear and direct line of references.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting upvoted, seems there is a glitch in the matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without some refactoring. Reflection could help but you still wouldn't be able to extend from that class or use it in any non runtime way.

I have found that this can happen with minimum refactoring

1. Identify the shared code
2. Extract it to a new shared project
3. Add the new project as a reference to all projects that need it